# Handling exception in background?

Tags: android-annotations

I found that I am forced to throw exception in a background thread:

```
@Background
void bootstrap() throws IOException {

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    restClient.setBearerAuth(Auth.token);
    UserID userIdJsonn = restClient.getUserId();
    Auth.user_id= userIdJsonn.getUser_id();
    PhoenixPlug.getInstance().ini();
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Of course, I've got this error:

```
Error:(619, 5) error: org.androidannotations.annotations.Background annotated methods should not declare throwing any exception
```

So, what's the recommended way to handle such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a background annotation, you have to catch the exception locally.